# How to hatch a box in plain (Xe)TeX

Tags: tables, xetex, plain-tex

I writing a document in Plain TeX with some [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle#cite_ref-3) diagrams. I wrote the following macro to generate such diagrams:

```
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\hrule}}
\def\puzzlebox#1{\vbox to 2em{\vfil\hbox to 2em{\hfil#1\hskip .5em}\vfil}}
\long\def\sixteenpuzzle#1{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule\tabskip=0pt
\halign{\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}\vrule\cr#1}}}
```

This macro can be used like this and works fine:

```
\sixteenpuzzle{
&1&2&3\cr\tablerule
4&5&6&7\cr\tablerule
8&9&10&11\cr\tablerule
12&13&14&15\cr\tablerule}
```

However, I would like to have the empty grid spot filled with a diagonal hatching so it is clear that the grid spot is unoccupied. Using XeTeX, how can I fill one cell of the grid with a diagonal hatching pattern?

If the way to do this involves completely changing the `\sixteenpuzzle` macro, I'm fine with that as it feels a bit like a clutch anyway.

Comment: I know there was a reason for the edit, but the site structure works best when questions ans answers are separated: makes things clear and 'predictable' to other users. I've rolled back, but if you really want the edit you can of course roll back my roll back.

Comment: @JosephWright No problem. Let me put this into an answer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain TeX a strange choice of format for a document (other than making a test case) but anyway, something like

[image]

```
\def\tablerule{\noalign{\hrule}}
\def\puzzlebox#1{%
\vbox to 2em{\vfil\hbox to 2em{%
\ifx\relax#1\relax
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 0 -10 m 20 10 l b Q }%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 0 -5  m 15 10 l b Q }%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 0 0   m 10 10 l b Q }%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 0 5   m 5  10 l b Q }%
%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 5  -10 m 20 5  l b Q }%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 10 -10 m 20 0  l b Q }%
\special {pdf: content q 0.5 0.5 0.5 RG 15 -10 m 20 -5 l b Q }%
\hfill
\else
\hfil#1\hskip .5em\fi}\vfil}}
\long\def\sixteenpuzzle#1{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\hrule\tabskip=0pt
\halign{\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}\vrule\cr#1}}}


\sixteenpuzzle{
&1&2&3\cr\tablerule
4&5&6&7\cr\tablerule
8&9&10&11\cr\tablerule
12&13&14&15\cr\tablerule}


\bye
```

Comment: This looks quite neat! Can you give me a link to a reference for the `\special` command you issued so I can tweak the parameters to my desire?

Comment: `texdoc dvipdfm` for the special, then the content after `pdf content` is literal PDF so any PDF reference, in this case  it sets a shade of grey then moves to some coordinate and then draws a line to some coordinate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am using Plain TeX because LaTeX is frustrating to work with: Everything is hidden behind layers and layers of extremely complicated macros and very hard to understand. With Plain TeX, I actually have a chance to understand why the control sequences I emit cause the result they do because I can understand the macros that are executed.

Comment: Hm... a little problem remains: When I have more than one empty spot in a puzzle configuration, the hatching is slightly off due to the width and height of the rules inbetween. Perhaps I can fix this by making the boxes around them have zero width/height.

Answer (score 2):

This is the macro I wrote as a result of the nice answer from [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle).

```
\def\boxaround#1{\vbox{\hrule\hbox{\vrule\kern2pt\vbox{\kern2pt#1\kern2pt}\kern2pt\vrule}\hrule}}
\def\hatchpattern{%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   8 m  2  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   6 m  4  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   4 m  6  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   2 m  8  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   0 m 10  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -2 m 12  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -4 m 14  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -6 m 16  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -8 m 18  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0 -10 m 20  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  2 -10 m 20   8 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  4 -10 m 20   6 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  6 -10 m 20   4 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  8 -10 m 20   2 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 10 -10 m 20   0 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 12 -10 m 20  -2 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 14 -10 m 20  -4 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 16 -10 m 20  -6 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 18 -10 m 20  -8 l b Q}}
\def\puzzlebox#1{\vbox to 2em{\vfil\hbox to 2em{\ifx\relax#1\relax\hatchpattern\hss\else\hfil#1\hskip .5em\fi}\vfil}}
\long\def\sixteenpuzzle#1{\boxaround{\offinterlineskip\hrule\tabskip=0pt
\halign{\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}&\vrule\puzzlebox{##}\vrule\cr#1}}}
```

This is how a resulting puzzle diagram looks:

[image: A permuted and a solved 15 puzzle]

I have later improved this macro set even further:

```
\def\boxaround#1#2{\hbox{\kern-0.2pt\vbox{\kern-0.2pt\hrule\hbox{\vrule\kern#1\vbox{%
\kern#1#2\kern#1}\kern#1\vrule}\hrule\kern-0.2pt}\kern-0.2pt}}
\def\hatchpattern{%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   8 m  2  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   6 m  4  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   4 m  6  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   2 m  8  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0   0 m 10  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -2 m 12  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -4 m 14  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -6 m 16  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0  -8 m 18  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  0 -10 m 20  10 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  2 -10 m 20   8 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  4 -10 m 20   6 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  6 -10 m 20   4 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w  8 -10 m 20   2 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 10 -10 m 20   0 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 12 -10 m 20  -2 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 14 -10 m 20  -4 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 16 -10 m 20  -6 l b Q}%
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w 18 -10 m 20  -8 l b Q}}
\def\puzzlebox#1{\boxaround{-0.2pt}{\vbox to 2em{\vfil\hbox to 2em{\hfil%
\ifx?#1$\bigcirc$\else#1\fi\ifcat A#1\hfil\else\hskip0.5em\fi}\vfil}}}
\def\hatchbox{\vbox to 2em{\vfil\hbox to 2em{\hatchpattern\hss}\vfil}}
\def\puzzlesquare#1{\ifx\relax#1\relax\hatchbox\else\puzzlebox{#1}\fi}
\def\puzzlediagram#1{\boxaround{2.2pt}{\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt\halign{&\puzzlesquare{##}\cr#1\crcr}}}
```

Now you can typeset diagrams of arbitrary size, e.g. this:

```
\halign{#\qquad&#\qquad&#\qquad&#\cr
\puzzlediagram{
1&3&8&9\cr
10&6&&4\cr
2&12&5&15\cr
14&7&13&11\cr}&
\puzzlediagram{
1&3&&\cr
&6&&4\cr
2&&5&\cr
&7&&\cr}&
\puzzlediagram{
?&?&A&A\cr
B&?&A&?\cr
?&C&?&D\cr
E&?&D&D\cr}&
\puzzlediagram{
1&3&&\cr
?&6&&4\cr
2&?&5&?\cr
?&7&?&?\cr}
\cr
\hfil(a)\hfil&\hfil(b)\hfil&\hfil(c)\hfil&\hfil(d)\hfil\cr}
```

yielding these diagrams:

[image]

Comment: I always used to solve it as the empty being "16" in the bottom right:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's possible, too. However, it's slightly easier to program if you start with zero and consider the 0 tile to be the empty one.

Comment: Aside: though it may be easier to program with the empty cell (0) at the top-left and 1–15, Knuth prefers to maintain tradition and write his programs for this puzzle with 1–15 and an empty cell (0) at the bottom-right, as @DavidCarlisle said. :-) (Search for "15PUZZLE" on [this page](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/programs.html) or see [typeset version](https://github.com/shreevatsa/knuth-literate-programs/blob/1b86fdc/programs/15puzzle-korf0.pdf).)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR This is interesting. I am actually working on a paper that expands Korf's additive pattern databases.