# How to fix this \special{pdf: content ...} so it doesn't corrupt the resulting PDF?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, ghostscript, specials

I use a `\special` command to drive some diagonal lines as a part of a [macro for drawing puzzles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393337/4595).  While these work fine when compiling with XeTeX, they seem to corrupt the resulting PDF document when using `pdftex` instead.  Here is a minimal reproducable example:

```
\special{pdf: content q 0 G 0.4 w
 0   8 m  2  10 l
 0   6 m  4  10 l
 0   4 m  6  10 l
 0   2 m  8  10 l
 0   0 m 10  10 l
 0  -2 m 12  10 l
 0  -4 m 14  10 l
 0  -6 m 16  10 l
 0  -8 m 18  10 l
 0 -10 m 20  10 l
 2 -10 m 20   8 l
 4 -10 m 20   6 l
 6 -10 m 20   4 l
 8 -10 m 20   2 l
10 -10 m 20   0 l
12 -10 m 20  -2 l
14 -10 m 20  -4 l
16 -10 m 20  -6 l
18 -10 m 20  -8 l
S Q}
\bye
```

When I open the resulting document in Adobe Acrobat or with Ghostscript, it'll complain about a defective page.  E.g. for `pdf2ps` we have:

```
$ pdf2ps test.pdf
   **** Error: File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
               Output may be incorrect.
```

What could the problem be?  How can I change the `\special` command to fix this issue?

Comment: Just replace `\special{pdf: content` with `\pdfliteral{`

Comment: @AlexG Doesn't seem to work with XeTeX though.  Is there a solution that works for both (aside from writing a compatibility shim)?

Comment: @AlexG Thanks.  I found that `\special{pdf: ...}` (without the `content` clause) also works.  Would you mind writing up an answer?

Comment: `\special{pdf: ...}` doesn't work for me with `xetex`. The page is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a conditional to abstract the backend differences

```latex
\ifdefined\XeTeXversion
  \protected\def\myspecial#1{\special{pdf:content q #1 Q}}
\else
  \protected\def\myspecial#1{\pdfliteral{q #1 Q}}
\fi
\myspecial{%
0 G 0.4 w
 0   8 m  2  10 l
 0   6 m  4  10 l
 0   4 m  6  10 l
 0   2 m  8  10 l
 0   0 m 10  10 l
 0  -2 m 12  10 l
 0  -4 m 14  10 l
 0  -6 m 16  10 l
 0  -8 m 18  10 l
 0 -10 m 20  10 l
 2 -10 m 20   8 l
 4 -10 m 20   6 l
 6 -10 m 20   4 l
 8 -10 m 20   2 l
10 -10 m 20   0 l
12 -10 m 20  -2 l
14 -10 m 20  -4 l
16 -10 m 20  -6 l
18 -10 m 20  -8 l
S}
\bye
```

(This could be extended for DVI mode, LuaTeX, etc.)

If you want to have everything *inside* a macro, one could go with

```
\protected\def\myspecial#1{%
  \special{%
    \ifdefined\XeTeXversion
      pdf:content q #1 Q
    \else
      pdf:q #1 Q
    \fi
  }%
}
\myspecial{%
0 G 0.4 w
 0   8 m  2  10 l
 0   6 m  4  10 l
 0   4 m  6  10 l
 0   2 m  8  10 l
 0   0 m 10  10 l
 0  -2 m 12  10 l
 0  -4 m 14  10 l
 0  -6 m 16  10 l
 0  -8 m 18  10 l
 0 -10 m 20  10 l
 2 -10 m 20   8 l
 4 -10 m 20   6 l
 6 -10 m 20   4 l
 8 -10 m 20   2 l
10 -10 m 20   0 l
12 -10 m 20  -2 l
14 -10 m 20  -4 l
16 -10 m 20  -6 l
18 -10 m 20  -8 l
S}
\bye
```

Comment: It's actually something OP wanted to avoid (engine detecting shim).

Comment: @AlexG Feel free to edit: I didn't double-check the q/Q situation. My reading of the question is it doesn't rule out the approach I've suggested. Although as `\special` does expansion, one could put it _inside_ the literal.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
\special{pdf:content ...}
```

(note the lack of space between `pdf:` and `content`).  This seems to work fine with both pdfTeX and XeTeX.

Comment: It doesn't (`pdftex`). Check with `pdf2ps`, Ghostscript complains. The string `content` is put verbatim into the page stream which is an error because there is no PDF operator named like this.

Comment: @AlexG Indeed, how strange.  It did work when I tried it a few days ago and I had accepted an answer already (which has since been deleted).

Comment: Yes, the deleted answer was mine. I flagged it for deletion after I discovered that there is no common special for both xetex and pdftex. You may need to use @Joseph's solution which queries the TeX engine in use.

Comment: @AlexG How unfortunate.